# GPS Daemon not working on RPi, but works on my Arch PC

Tags: pi-4, uart, systemd, gps

I followed this [Adafruit Tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-hat-for-raspberry-pi/use-gpsd); trying to make GPS Daemon work on RPi4- on Raspberry OS minimal. Here is my situation:

- I can see NMEA data is coming thru `minicom -b 9600 -D /dev/ttyUSB0`.
- There is no error showed after executing `sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock`
- There is no error showed after `disabling` or `enabling` daemons using systemd as instructed in the tutorial
- **Issue**: `cgps -s` & `gpsmon` not showing me data.
- **Update**: Actually `gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0` shows the data. But only `gpsmon` itself not showing data. (So does it means some sort of systemd service error?)
- I tested on Archlinux on my Laptop exactly same thing, `cps -s` & `gpsmon` shows the all gps data.

What am I missing ???

---

Sample output (in RPi):

```
$cgps -s

┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│    Time:       n/a                        ││PRN:   Elev:  Azim:  SNR:  Used: │
│    Latitude:   n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Longitude:  n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Altitude:   n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Speed:      n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Heading:    n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Climb:      n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Status:     NO FIX (0 secs)            ││                                 │
│    Longitude Err:   n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Latitude Err:    n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Altitude Err:    n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Course Err:      n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Speed Err:       n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Time offset:     n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Grid Square:     n/a                   ││                                 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────┘└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

Sample output (in Arch):

```
$gps -s
┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐┌──────────────────Seen 14/Used  9┐
│ Time         2021-11-30T04:39:34.000Z (0) ││GNSS   PRN  Elev   Azim   SNR Use│
│ Latitude          43.08521667 N           ││GP 10   10  56.0  260.0  20.0  Y │
│ Longitude        141.33366500 E           ││GP 12   12  60.0  131.0  35.0  Y │
│ Alt (HAE, MSL)     141.404,     32.808 ft ││GP 15   15  20.0  121.0  20.0  Y │
│ Speed              0.02 mph               ││GP 19   19   8.0   50.0  23.0  Y │
│ Track (true, var):   182.8,  -9.6     deg ││GP 23   23  45.0  202.0  28.0  Y │
│ Climb           -177.17 ft/min            ││GP 25   25  41.0  183.0  25.0  Y │
│ Status          3D FIX (7 secs)           ││GP 32   32  34.0  304.0  11.0  Y │
│ Long Err  (XDOP, EPX)   0.87, +/- 42.6 ft ││QZ  1  193  70.0  171.0  33.0  Y │
│ Lat Err   (YDOP, EPY)   0.92, +/- 45.5 ft ││QZ  2  194  55.0  178.0  35.0  Y │
│ Alt Err   (VDOP, EPV)   0.90, +/- 67.9 ft ││GP 17   17   3.0   27.0   0.0  N │
│ 2D Err    (HDOP, CEP):  1.05, +/- 82.3 ft ││GP 21   21   2.0  324.0   0.0  N │
│ 3D Err    (PDOP, SEP):  1.38, +/- 99.7 ft ││GP 24   24  51.0   59.0  16.0  N │
│ Time Err  (TDOP):       1.26              ││GP 31   31   1.0  250.0   0.0  N │
│ Geo Err   (GDOP):       2.69              ││SB128   41  14.0  247.0   0.0  N │
│ ECEF X, VX              n/a    n/a        ││                                 │
│ ECEF Y, VY              n/a    n/a        ││                                 │
│ ECEF Z, VZ              n/a    n/a        ││                                 │
│ Speed Err (EPS)        +/- 62.0 mph       ││                                 │
│ Track Err (EPD)         n/a               ││                                 │
│ Time offset            -72.484989051 s    ││                                 │
│ Grid Square             QN03qc00          ││                                 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────┘└─────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was following seems to working:

Changing `/etc/default/gpsd` to following

```
$ cat /etc/default/gpsd
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.

# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="true"

# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="true"

# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G"

GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.socket"
```

And then enable & start `gpsd.socket` seems make it work.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable gpsd.socket
$ sudo systemctl start gpsd.socket
```

---

Still I don't fully understand it. If you know more about these, why it didn't work in the 1st place etc, Please put comment below.